# Need to store variable length bit code in the stl::bitset

Tags: c++

I am working on compression of file.I have generated codes in binary form for distinct symbols exist in file, using shannon fano algorithm and i want to store these codes in bitset.
Codes are resides in map.Now my problem is, as the codes for different symbol are of different length, how i will do this?

Comment: have you looked at std::bitset?

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.DynamicBitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).

Comment: I need to take a bitset of size 8 so that i can easily write that bitset into the file as a bye.